# Spring Websocket opens the web page, but cannot connect to the websocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

- WebSocketConfig.java - https://pastebin.com/G4iUk5Q2
- ChatController.java - https://pastebin.com/TPxwxaKm
- ChatMessage.java - https://pastebin.com/qbfcSvTe
- MessageType.java - https://pastebin.com/kMA3MPGd
- index.html - https://pastebin.com/HBD6Tn6L
- main.js - https://pastebin.com/hn3m3p97

I'm connecting using `localhost:8080` which produces the "login" page, however, when I connect, it produces "Could not connect to the WebSocket server. Please refresh this page to try again!" located in line 50 in `main.js`.

I'm going to be honest, I am *very* new to Spring and all of this. I've watched multiple tutorials, trying to figure out why something is not working. They all produce the same error. I'm running a gradle application, to which I will provide my `build.gradle` below. I will also attempt to show my full console log.

Console Log - https://gist.github.com/beanbeanjuice/035f8dcd8e5b347eab87558fe713d8c8

A few errors are produced, such as a a `LibraryNotFoundError` for `org.apache.tomcat.jni`, however, after some research, it appears that that is "normal" behaviour.

The second notable error is a `ClassNotFoundException` for `java.net.UnixDomainSocketAddress` which seems to go away when switching to JDK 16. However, switchin to JDK 16 does not fix the issue.

Here is my build.grade;

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.0.0'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

def versionName

try {
    def result = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(file('beta.json').text)
    versionName = result.bot.version
} catch (ignored) {
    versionName = 'v0.0.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '15'
group 'com.beanbeanjuice'
mainClassName = 'com.beanbeanjuice.main.CafeBot'
version versionName

repositories {

    // Central Maven repository.
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases'
    }

}

dependencies {

    // JUnit, for Unit Testing
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: '5.8.0-M1'
    testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine'

    // Json Slurper
    implementation group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-json', version: '3.0.8'

    // Jetbrains Annotations
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains', name: 'annotations', version: '21.0.1'

    // Discord JDA, for Discord things
    implementation group: 'net.dv8tion', name: 'JDA', version: '4.2.1_265'

    // Twitch Connections
    implementation group: 'com.github.twitch4j', name: 'twitch4j', version: '1.4.0'

    // Lava Player
    implementation group: 'com.sedmelluq', name: 'lavaplayer', version: '1.3.77'

    // Spotify API
    implementation group: 'se.michaelthelin.spotify', name: 'spotify-web-api-java', version: '6.5.4'

    // JSOUP for Parsing
    implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.13.1'

    // JSON
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.12.3'

    // Logback
    implementation group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'

    // SQL Connection
    implementation group: 'org.mariadb.jdbc', name: 'mariadb-java-client', version: '2.7.3'

    // Time Stuff (For Birthdays)
    implementation group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.10.10'

    // Apple Music/Itunes API
    implementation group: 'be.ceau', name: 'itunes-api', version: '4.6.0'

    // Spring Stuff
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-websocket', version: '2.4.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty', version: '2.4.3'
    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.4.3'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileTestJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

I suspect it is something to do with my computer, but at this point I am completely lost.

Edit #1: It seems like something is happening causing it to get a 404 error even though it DOES connect through the browser. The landing page for the websocket works, but the websocket itself does not. Here is the error;

```
05-30-2021 16:10:44.984 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Rfc6265CookiePr DEBUG  Cookies: Parsing b[]: Webstorm-7aec51c5=4c5a97a9-ed16-42bc-89aa-409f0b675f69; Webstorm-7aec5584=a3831a74-27ec-4566-a79c-66e02fe05627
05-30-2021 16:10:44.984 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          AuthenticatorBa DEBUG  Security checking request GET /console/info
05-30-2021 16:10:44.984 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          RealmBase       DEBUG    No applicable constraints defined
05-30-2021 16:10:44.984 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          AuthenticatorBa DEBUG  Not subject to any constraint
05-30-2021 16:10:44.984 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Parameters      DEBUG  Set encoding to UTF-8
05-30-2021 16:10:44.985 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Parameters      DEBUG  Decoding query null UTF-8
05-30-2021 16:10:44.985 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Parameters      DEBUG  Start processing with input [t=1622405444981]
05-30-2021 16:10:44.985 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          DispatcherServl DEBUG  GET "/console/info?t=1622405444981", parameters={masked}
05-30-2021 16:10:44.985 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          SimpleUrlHandle DEBUG  Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [Classpath [META-INF/resources/], Classpath [resources/], Classpath [static/], Classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
05-30-2021 16:10:44.986 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          ResourceHttpReq DEBUG  Resource not found
05-30-2021 16:10:44.986 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          DispatcherServl DEBUG  Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
05-30-2021 16:10:44.986 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          [localhost]     DEBUG  Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
05-30-2021 16:10:44.986 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          DispatcherServl DEBUG  "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error?t=1622405444981", parameters={masked}
05-30-2021 16:10:44.987 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          RequestMappingH DEBUG  Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
05-30-2021 16:10:45.002 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          HttpEntityMetho DEBUG  Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.002 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          HttpEntityMetho DEBUG  Writing [{timestamp=Sun May 30 16:10:44 EDT 2021, status=404, error=Not Found, path=/console/info}]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.020 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          DispatcherServl DEBUG  Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
05-30-2021 16:10:45.020 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          [dispatcherServ DEBUG   Disabling the response for further output
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Http11InputBuff DEBUG  Before fill(): parsingHeader: [true], parsingRequestLine: [true], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [0], byteBuffer.limit(): [0], end: [415]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          SocketWrapperBa DEBUG  Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2afef747:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@20069c37:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:4002 remote=/127.0.0.1:56600]], Read from buffer: [0]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          NioEndpoint     DEBUG  Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2afef747:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@20069c37:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:4002 remote=/127.0.0.1:56600]], Read direct from socket: [0]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Http11InputBuff DEBUG  Received []
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Http11Processor DEBUG  Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2afef747:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@20069c37:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:4002 remote=/127.0.0.1:56600]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          Http11NioProtoc DEBUG  Pushed Processor [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor@795e5110]
05-30-2021 16:10:45.021 -0400 http-nio-4002-exec-5                          NioEndpoint     DEBUG  Registered read interest for [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@2afef747:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@20069c37:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:4002 remote=/127.0.0.1:56600]]
```

I'm not sure why the 404 is happening. I'm doing more research but, but everything I'm trying is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My websocket packages had to be in the same, or in a sub package of my `Main` class. GG.